# Using firestore() in a method

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to load data from a Google Cloud Firestore. I can load the whole set of data OK, but I can't call a method and get a single record.

Vue-firestore comes from https://github.com/gdg-tangier/vue-firestore but the documentation does not cover this.

This works

```
new Vue({
  el : '#app',

  ...

  firestore() {
    return {
        pages: db.collection('pages')
        }
    },
```

This does not

```
methods: {

    showPage: function(id) {
        console.log("Getting content for: " + id);

        firestore() { return { page : db.collection('pages').where("title", "==", id) } };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.page));
        },
```

How does one the firestore() outside of where it gets setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood what `firestore()` does.

`firestore()` is not a call to a running database. It is more to akin to establishing a connection which was previously assigned to db.

The reason this did not work was because, there was already a connection, db.